# Error when plotting basic plotly line graph

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am receiving the following message when trying to plot a frequency/time line graph on plotly:

```
Error in if (has_group(trace)) tryNULL(dplyr::group_vars(dat)) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is the code and dataframe that I am currently plotting:

```
`Week beginning` <-as.Date(c("2015-01-05", "2015-01-12", "2015-01-19", "2015-01-26", "2015-02-02", "2015-02-09", "2015-02-16", "2015-02-23", "2015-03-02", "2015-03-09"))
Freq <- as.integer(c(2,5,1,5,5,1,2,2,3,2))

df <- data.frame(`Week beginning`, Freq)

FreqByWeek <- plot_ly(df, x= ~`Week beginning`) %>% 
  add_trace(y =~`Freq`, type = "scatter", modes ="lines")

FreqByWeek
```

I am trying to knit render this plot in a HTML file. The error shows up in the final line where I attempt to print the plot. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just use `plot_ly(df, x= ~\`Week beginning\`, y = ~Freq, mode = "lines", type = "scatter")` without `add_trace` or where you looking for something different? Also try `mode` instead of `modes`...

Comment: I was also able to get it to work with `mode` instead of `modes`

Comment: Thank you! That was what the issue was!